# What are the general applications of Computer Science in the field of Psychology?

Tags: computation-models

I am keenly interested to do a project in Computer Science that can aid to address the problems in the field of Psychology. Now I want to know what are the most general and research-oriented issues or problems areas in Psychology that can be solved through computation or at least aid to be solved via Computer Science.
Looking for authentic answers. Thank you

Comment: Topic is a bit too broad, moreover if you think about project it is probably more related to programming. Tag computation-models is not proper here. Could you give at least one valid example to shed some light on your expectations? Do you treat data acquisition or HCI as valid topic?

Comment: Perhaps you should look in the direction of [cognitive science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_science).

Comment: @PålGD That is a good suggestion. Please do take your time to go through my own answer to my question as it elaborates more about quest and curiosity. Thank you

Comment: @Evil I agree with your point what you mean. For more elaboration, please do read my own answer to my question here. Also I wonder if I should post this question on the forums of Cognitive Science  or maybe Theoretical Computer Science as I am also looking for computational and non-computational problem/research areas in Psychology.  Let me have your valuable suggestion one you have read my answer.

Comment: I am afraid that some of your topics are not related to Psychology, rather speculations, besides, I am lost, I thought your project should be connected with both at some deeper level. As a warning, the answer box is not for extending the question. 1. Philosophical question about perceived limitations or specific cognitive task. 2. Some asumptions are invalid, clinical depression is cured with perscription drugs and psychotherapy afterwards, it is impossible to overcome it. 3. Philosophical question. 4. HCI is not related to psychotherapy in any sense. In very loose sense, simple answer is yes

Comment: provided you get some NLP in place, implement say DSM V and ICD 11 tests, for psychiatrist part, it is hard, as this is empirical not algorithmical task. 5. It is speculative about Cryptography, then some assumptions made, that people would like to proceed in some direction (research shows they do not and outcome is far worse than expected). With getting rid of some hate, well, problem is at higher level ... That said, this site as well as CogSci and TCS are not forums but Q&A sites. For sure this doesn't have a chance at TCS. I suggest chat and do not really see CS part as on-topic here.

Comment: affective computing

Comment: @TomR What is that exactly? Please elaborate.

Comment: E.g. see Steunebrink, B.R. (2010). The Logical Structure of Emotions. Ph.D. thesis, Utrecht University, The Netherlands. ISBN 978-90-393-5329-5 and also the publications in IEEE Transactions on Affective Computing.

Comment: There is also woebot therapy chatbot from Stanford - direct application, automation of psychotherapy.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some of the areas that intuitively come into my mind where Computer Science and Psychology can go along together. As a student of Computer Science, one has to study the following core subjects at the undergrad level that are either directly or indirectly related to Psychology:

***1. Data Structures and Algorithms:*** All the data structures do exist in the real world and the human mind perceives them to store, arrange, sort and search the required data as per their strength and limitation. Now the question arises, could there be a data structure or algorithm that is beyond the perception and capacity of human mind? Perhaps certainly or maybe.

***2. Design and Analysis of Algorithms:*** Could there be a general algorithm for curing a mental disease, achieving happiness, finding love or the best match, finding career, overcome stress or depression, defeating a rival, rehabilitating a heroine addict or leading a "perfect life"? All of such aspects of human life can be addressed computationally. And yes the answers to these questions are indeed subjective and debatable as well.

***3. Artificial Intelligence:*** Can we ever have machines more intelligent than humans? Oh yes, we certainly have such intelligent machines. But do such machines recognize vision and pattern as we humans do? That is an area of continuous research in Computer Science.

***4. Human Computer Interaction:*** In the modern world, humans do interact with computers almost on a daily basis. Commercial hardware, software applications and games, all of them are designed with the "interface" keeping in view the human user's perception, expectation and limitation in consideration. Now the question arises: Can we have Computers as our personal psychiatrists? Can we treat mental or psychological patients with Computer-Aided Psychotherapy? I really want to explore!!!!

***5. Professional/Ethical Issues in Computing:*** Can we ever be able to fully secure personal or professional data via Computers? Can we get rid of pornography from the internet? Can we develop a game that counters games leading to suicide like ["Blue Whale"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Whale_(game))? Can we rid the world from religious fanaticism, terrorism, racism and hate crimes via Computer Science?  All of such questions and problem areas are pending to be addressed.

Comment: My answer to my own question helps clarifying my question further and does describe my aim what I am precisely researching. Thank you

Comment: Regarding point 3 see Artificial General Intelligence and Cognitive architectures, currently conference is going in Prague!

Comment: "All the data structures do exist in the real world and the human mind perceives them to store, arrange, sort and search the required data as per their strength and limitation." This is a bold claim. Can you offer any evidence for this bold metaphysical and epistemological assertion?

Comment: @ubadub No data structure can ever exist out of the real world and human mind perceives them for manipulating data, no matter it is quantitative or qualitative.May I ask you what do you exactly find "metaphysical" in my answer?